# Schedule future post to custom post status instead of publish?

Tags: post-status, scheduled-posts

I've been doing some research into custom post statuses and scheduling posts and I had a question: I was wondering if it were possible to schedule a post to got from `future` to a custom post status instead of `publish`?  Main reason I'm asking is that I have a custom post type called `stream` and I've created a custom publish meta box that allows a user to select 2 post statuses: `online` and `offline`.  I'm trying to make it so that if I set a future date, the stream post will transition to `online` instead of `publish` as it normally would.

My train of thought would be to hijack via filter the post status to automatically transition to `online` whenever WordPress tries to set it to `publish`.  Would that be a viable option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea:

You could try to use the `future_to_publish` action to change the post status:

```
add_action('future_to_publish', 'set_status_online_wpse_95701'); 
function set_status_online_wpse_95701( $post ) { 
    if ( $post && $post->post_type==="stream"){
       $post->post_status="online"; // change the post_status
       wp_update_post( $post );
    }    
}
```